# Register a custom tensorflow operation that could be used in tensorflow C++, which itself uses some existing tensorflow operation

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel

I’m trying to register a custom tensorflow operation that I could later use in C++.
The operation is required to use an already existing tensorflow operation as-

```
Output output1 = tensorflow::ops::DeepCopy(scope, tensor);
```

I’ve created `custom_op.cc` file that contains following as shown in official documentation of tensorflow to create a custom op (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op )-

1. Defining the op interface
2. Implementing the kernel for the op
3. Registering it with tensorflow kernel

I placed `custom_op.cc` in following directory:

```
//tensorflow/core/user_ops/custom_op.cc
```

**System Information-**
Tensorflow version – 1.14.0
Bazel version – 0.24.1
OS – Windows 10 Professional

When I try to build this tensorflow package with bazel, the following problem arises-
`custom_op.cc` includes a header file `tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h` (I had to include it because `DeepCopy` is declared in this header file), which further contains more headers (`tensorlfow/cc/ops/array_ops.h`, `tensorflow/cc/ops/candidate_sampling_ops.h`, and so on...) but these headers are not pre existing in tensorflow package and are generated while building tensorflow with bazel.

So, while building tensorflow with bazel with the following command-

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so
```

I’m getting the following error-

```
.\tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h(19): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tensorflow/cc/ops/array_ops.h': No such file or directory
```

I’ve also tried it with different targets but still get the same error.

Later, I tried it building as incremental build, I first built tensorflow using bazel successfully without adding any custom tensorflow operation, and then tried to build it again after adding `custom_op.cc` file in the `//tensorflow/core/user_ops/` directory, then I get the following error -

```
undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//tensorflow/core:user_ops_op_lib':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'tensorflow/core/user_ops/custom_op.cc':
  'bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/cc/ops/array_ops.h'
Target //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so failed to build
```

Any idea that I can use to resolve this issue?